# How to take random sample from mysql database with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

I have a table with some users information, sex, date of birth, "category", etc

I need to take a random sample, but with the following results:

> 75% Women
> 25% Men

> 50% Age between 25-35
>   40% Age between 36-40
>   10% Age between 41-60

To a total of `2000` records.

Is there anyway to do this directly in MySQL?

Comment: Nothing... i have no clue... i mean.. I can make a random selection limit to 2000 records, with some basic rules, but how can i make sure that the 50% of age between 25-35 has some women + some men?

Comment: you can't actually guarantee "that the 50% of age between 25-35 has some women + some men" as that wouldn't be a true random sample. That would be selective. e.g. if I recorded every 3rd person in a line they may all be men, but there were women in the line.
you may be better taking it a section at a time, like so:
750 men age 25-35;
250 women age 25-35; etc.

Comment: Looks like you'd have to go with union

Comment: @DeanWinchester but the table is the same, how can union help?

Comment: OK it's a bit tricky, I just realised you need to meet both conditions. So `(select something from users where age between 25 and 35 and sex = 'male' order by rand() limit 2000*0.5*0.75) union (select something from users where age between 25 and 35 and sex = 'female' order by rand() limit 2000*0.5*0.25) union (...)`, but this can't guarantee you get 2000 results

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use order by or limit within a Union Statement in for each sql queries. They can be used at the end.

So its better to use a stored procedure for the output.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USER_DATA_RAND()
BEGIN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE USER_TMP
ID INT,
DATE_OF_BIRTH DATE,
CATEGORY STRING,
AGE INT)
INSERT INTO USER_TMP
select sex, date_of_birth, `category`,age from users where age between 25 and 35 and sex = 'male' order by rand() limit 2000*0.5*0.25) ;
INSERT INTO USER_TMP
select sex, date_of_birth, `category`,age from users where age between 25 and 35 and sex = 'female' order by rand() limit 2000*0.5*0.75) ;
INSERT INTO USER_TMP
select sex, date_of_birth, `category`,age from users where age between 36 and 40 and sex = 'male' order by rand() limit 2000*0.40*0.25) ;
INSERT INTO USER_TMP
select sex, date_of_birth, `category`,age from users where age between 36 and 40 and sex = 'female' order by rand() limit 2000*0.40*0.75) ;
INSERT INTO USER_TMP
select sex, date_of_birth, `category`,age from users where age between 41 and 60 and sex = 'male' order by rand() limit 2000*0.10*0.25) ;
INSERT INTO USER_TMP
select sex, date_of_birth, `category`,age from users where age between 41 and 60 and sex = 'female' order by rand() limit 2000*0.10*0.75) ;

SELECT * FROM USER_TMP;
END
```